# On Click Search Table, Highlight Value In Another Table and With That Sections Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, highlight

What I'm trying to do is get the value from one table cell and search 4 other tables that are in their own tab sections (Tab Green Section, Tab Yellow Section, Tab Purple Section and Tab Grey Section).

If you are in that section you will get that Sections Color and it will highlight that values row with sections color.

1. On the table I click and get the value from that cell
2. It searches through all tables which have the class = "eventsSearch"
3. It then finds all the value in that table and highlights the row in
   that Sections color

[image]

My issues is I'm having trouble getting the Tab Section Color to highlight the rows matching TAB COLOR.

```js
 $(function() {

   $('#DashEvent').find('td').click(function(highlightedEventColor) {
     selectedEvent = $(this).text();
     console.log(selectedEvent);

     var tables = $('.eventsSearch');
     tables.find('tr').each(function(index, row) {
       var allCells = $(row).find('td');
       if (allCells.length > 0) {
         var found = false;
         allCells.each(function(index, td) {
           var regExp = new RegExp(selectedEvent, 'i');
           if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
             //alert(selectedEvent);
             found = true;
             return false;
           }
         });
         if (found == true) $(row).css("background-color", highlightedEventColor);
         else $(row).css("background-color", "#f9f9f9");
       }
     });
   });

   $(".Green_td").on("click", function() {
     function activaTab(tab) {
       $("#Green_tab").find('a').trigger('click');
       //$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
       console.log(tab);
     };
     activaTab('Green_tab');
     var highlightedEventColor = "#eaffa9";
     return highlightedEventColor
   });

   $(".Yellow_td").on("click", function() {
     function activaTab(tab) {
       $("#Yellow_tab").find('a').trigger('click');
       //$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
       console.log(tab);
     };
     activaTab('Yellow_tab');
     var highlightedEventColor = "#fff711";
     return highlightedEventColor
   });

 });
```

Comment: Now, I'm passing back the highlightedEventColor , but I'm only getting the color black...